Can EE 2.4 MySql db be used with EE 7.4
My client wants to upgrade their EE 2.4 site to the current EE 7.4. Will the old db work with the current version?
If there are is any other info or caveats about such an upgrade they would be appreciated.

The core of ExpressionEngine can be upgraded from version 2 to version 7 without a problem.  I would recommend jumping directly from version 2 to 7 (not going to version 3, 4, 5 etc... the updater in version 7 is significantly better).
You will need to source the updated versions of the add-ons currently in use on the site as well.  If you can post a list of the add-ons currently in use we would be happy to provide some feedback on the best path forward for each one.

So these are the modules I have installed on the v2 site
Channel  2.0.1
Comment  2.2
Email  2
Emoticon         2
FireMail         1.8
Freeform         3.1.3
jQuery  1
Mailing List 3
Member  2.1
Pages  2.2
RSS          2
SafeCracker 2.1
Search  2.1
SEO Lite            1.3.5
Statistics         2
Wygwam  2.4.0.2

over on Reddit there's a similar discussion going on that may contain some helpfull pointers: https://www.reddit.com/r/expressionengine/comments/1hf0gr6/upgrade_migrate_expressionengine_site_from_270_to/
If you need more help, find us there or on the Slack channel https://join.slack.com/t/eecms/shared_invite/zt-2rsbr68k3-hjW3DwYmNtTKLHt4Ee3v6Q
